# Can annotations or its methods have the access modifiers like private, default or protected?

Tags: java

And do annotations need to be defined in a separate file? What are the kind of restrictions that apply to annotations?

Answer (score 2):

> Can annotations or its methods have the access modifiers like private, default or protected?

An annotation can have access modifiers with the same restrictions as interface access modifiers.  (For example, a `protected` or `private` annotation is only allowed if it is nested.)

An annotation element (i.e. a "method") is implicitly `public`.

> And do annotations need to be defined in a separate file?

No.  Annotations can be nested in classes, for example.

> What are the kind of restrictions that apply to annotations?

Too broad.  Refer to the Java Language Specification for all restrictions that apply annotations.  Reading all of [Chapter 9](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-9.html) probably covers most of them :-)

Comment: You can restrict where an annotation can be applied by specifying the \@Target annotation. You can also restrict where it is visible with the \@Rentention annotation +1